# X axis labels not responding to arguments in CorPlot

Tags: correlation, x-axis

I've been using corPlot from the psych package for my correlation plots since it offers better options for me in terms of plot layouts than corrplot. A couple months ago, both y-axis and x-axis label font sizes responded to the "cex.axis" argument. However, now it seems the x-axis labels don't respond anymore to certain arguments, which results in me having x and y labels in different sizes and outlining

It no longer responds to the xlas argument or cex.axis argument (to adjust the font size), or the xaxt = "n" argument (so that I could add the x axis manually). Even more peculiar, using the xaxt "n" argument, the x axis and tick marks disappear, but not the labels. However, the labels do respond to the xsrt argument (can orient/rotate any number of degrees), and to the labels argument to give it all variables a certain label. It seems to be a certain bug in the package since the y axis responds normally to all arguments. Anyone who knows about this or has corPlot changed? Because all this did not occur a couple months ago with the same code.

This is the code I've been using:

> 

```
correlationplot.cog.mnt <- data[,c(4,7:8,13,19:20,24:32,42:51)]
corr.test(correlationplot.cog.mnt,method = "spearman", use = "pairwise")
corrvalues.cog <-corr.test(correlationplot.cog.mnt,method = "spearman", use = "pairwise")$r
pvalues.cog <-corr.test(correlationplot.cog.mnt,method = "spearman", use = "pairwise")$p

par(bty="n")
par(oma=c(1, 0.05, 1, 0.05))
format.pval(c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001))
gr <- colorRampPalette(c("#70030e", "#ab5620", "white","#0270b0", "#010145"))
corPlot(corrvalues.cog, cex = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.5, xlas = 2, upper = FALSE, pval= pvalues.cog, stars = TRUE, colors= T, gr=gr)
```

I already tried
*cex.axis, cex.names, xaxt, xlas,
*removing and reinstalling R
*opening a new script with the same code
... none of this helped